# How to combine "not" operators using the spring data Criteria builder

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

To setup the scene, the query I want to produce is similar to the following that I've manually written. The idea is that I want to exclude a date range from the result set. In this case, nothing from today, but if there's any in the past or in the future, I want them!

```
{
  "createdOn": {
    $not: {
      "$lte": ISODate("2020-20-23T23:59:59.999999999"),
      "$gte": ISODate("2020-20-23T00:00"),
    }
  }
}
```

The code I am using to try and get the above is the following:

```java
Criteria.where("createdOn")
    .not()
    .gte(LocalDate.now().atTime(LocalTime.MIN))
    .lte(LocalDate.now().atTime(LocalTime.MAX))
```

However, that generates the following:

```
{
  "createdOn": {
    "$not": {
      "$gte": {
        "$java": "2020-03-23T00:00"
      }
    },
    "$lte": {
      "$java": "2020-03-23T23:59:59.999999999"
    }
  }
}
```

If I changed the code to add another `not` before the `lte` it still produces the same output.

Is there any way of producing the query I want, or an alternate way of excluding a range of dates from the result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your `mongo` shell and the MongoDB Spring Java code. The shell code works fine, but the corresponding Java code using the `not()` doesn't work (I don't know why).

Here is another way working with the same functionality your looking for:

> ...nothing from today, but if there's any in the past or in the future

I am using the following input documents:

```
{ _id: 1, createdOn: ISODate("2020-03-21T12:05:00") },
{ _id: 2, createdOn: ISODate("2020-03-28T18:33:00") },
{ _id: 3, createdOn: ISODate("2020-03-24T01:56:00") }
```

And, assuming *today's date*: `ISODate("2020-03-24T02:50:04.992Z")`, the result should exclude the document with `_id: 3`, where the `createdOn` is within *today*.

The `mongo` shell query:

```
db.collection.find( {
  $or: [
    { createdOn: { $gt: ISODate("2020-03-24T23:59:59.99") } },
    { createdOn: { $lt: ISODate("2020-03-24T00:00:00") } }
  ]
} )
```

This returns the documents with `_id`'s `1` and `2` (these exclude today's date).

The corresponding Java code:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s");
Date fromDate = dateFormat.parse("2020-03-24 00:00:00");
Date toDate = dateFormat.parse("2020-03-24 23:59:59");

Criteria c = new Criteria().orOperator(
                           Criteria.where("createdOn").lt(fromDate),
                           Criteria.where("createdOn").gt(toDate) );        
Query q = Query.query(c);

MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "testDB");
List<Document> result = mongoOps.find(q, Document.class, "collection");
result.forEach(doc -> System.out.println(doc.toJson()));
```

Comment: You know what, the or operator should have been obvious since that's how you'd have dealt with it in normal SQL! Haha. Thanks.

I guess there's also a bug to possibly raise in the spring mongodb project. So I'll go do that.