# Spring Data MongoDB date time range query issue

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring data MongoDB with Spring Boot and writing the custom queries using `Criteria`. I need to get the data from mongo database based on datatime range. In query I am passing `statDatetime > 24-Mar-2020T00.00.00.000Z` and `StartDateTime < 27-Mar-2020T23.59.00.000Z` to get data that fall under the given range, but here spring data mongo db considering each day as one day range, and foaming the query with 4 AND conditions for above range.

Below is the query that I had. here i am checking `Start_Date_Time` along with other parameters:

```
final Criteria criteria = where(BASE).in(base)
                               .andOperator(where(SEQUENCE_INFO_KEY)
                               .is(sequenceInfoKey),
                          where(START_DATE_TIME).gte(startDateTime),
                          where(START_DATE_TIME).lte(endDateTime),
                          where(DELETED).is(false));

final Query query = new Query(criteria);
```

Query forming as:

```
     {
        "$and": [
          {},
          {
            "$or": [
              {
                "$and": [
                  {
                    "startDateTime": {
                      "$gte": {
                        "$date": 1585008000000
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "startDateTime": {
                      "$lte": {
                        "$date": 1585094340000
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "$and": [
                  {
                    "startDateTime": {
                      "$gte": {
                        "$date": 1585094400000
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "startDateTime": {
                      "$lte": {
                        "$date": 1585180740000
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "$and": [
                  {
                    "startDateTime": {
                      "$gte": {
                        "$date": 1585180800000
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "startDateTime": {
                      "$lte": {
                        "$date": 1585267140000
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "$and": [
                  {
                    "startDateTime": {
                      "$gte": {
                        "$date": 1585267200000
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "startDateTime": {
                      "$lte": {
                        "$date": 1585353540000
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
```

Please let me know how to avoid this individual date range forming ?

Comment: you realize those time ranges are not contiguous?

Comment: Here are couple of posts with date range queries using Spring Data MongoDB: 
[How to combine “not” operators using the spring data Criteria builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60819805/how-to-combine-not-operators-using-the-spring-data-criteria-builder/60825286#60825286) and [Why spring data mongo not returning the field having time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60083930/why-spring-data-mongo-not-returning-the-field-having-time).

Comment: can you tried where(START_DATE_TIME).gte(startDateTime).lte(endDateTime) ?